# Top bar menu not visible in mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am using WordPress 4.3.1 with Newspaper theme. The top bar menu having social links and buttons like "submit content", "contact us" "date" etc is not visible in the mobile view or whenever I make the screen size small. Please help me with issue.

Website name : www.teachologist.in

Answer (score 1):

In the theme style sheet there are media queries that hide the elements at `max-width: 767px`. You would need to remove the `display: none;` and perhaps replace with other appropriate styles to make the menu still look good on small devices.

See `wp-content/themes/Newspaper/style.css` Line 1185

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .td-header-top-menu-full {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

And see `wp-content/themes/Newspaper/style.css` Line 4946

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .td-header-sp-top-menu {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```